# Angular unit tests random failure: Multiple components match node with tagname

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jenkins, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm facing an issue with our angular unit tests that happen only in the server and not locally

```
1) should save stagingArea && connections/disconnections when click edit

StagingAreaPageComponent

Error: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname button.


8) View and Edit: Open the file in an editor - Should view file with extension via edit button

ContextViewerComponent

Error: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname mat-icon.

should emit events when button clicked


    FabMenuComponent
    
      Error: NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname app-progress-button
```

I tried to reproduce it locally but it's not happening, and I didn't find a way how to start debugging and invest

- Angular version: 12

  Jasmine and karma used

Command used to run unit tests in server: `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI --code-coverage`
Any help is appreciated

Comment: If it happens on the server and not locally I would start by reseting both envs by deleting package.lock and node_modules and reinstall everything

Comment: Hi I followed your instruction and it helps me! now I can reproduce them locally :) but still not able how to fix them

Comment: Hi @YohanDahmani, I would ask why removing package-lock.json and reinstall node modules helped to reproduce the error?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed You may be having a duplicate selector, search globally with `app-progress-button` in your project

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I just know from past experiences that when you have an issue on the server and not in local it's probably something to do with the cache or something. Maybe the server pulled à `npm install` instead of an `npm ci` and had no cache while you had in local and did not commit your package.lock.
Maybe a package was updated and you have `^` before the version number so the package was updated

Comment: Thx for the update! I tried to search for the utility of package-lock.json and I didn't get good explanation for that